# Gamemaker multiplayer using 39dll

Tags: node.js, game-maker

I am making a gamemaker multiplayer game using 39dll's tcp sockets. As I want to host the server (and my javascript knowledge is a lot better), I use node.js for the server. I have already got gamemaker to connect to the server and send data, but now I have a problem with receiving data. After reading a lot, it seems that I need to do that like so: `sock=tcpaccept(global.tcpConnection,1);`. If sock is a negative number, the creation of the 'listening' interface failed. It returns me the number `-10022`. I can not find much information about it, so if anyone knows why this problem occurs and how to fix it would be very nice.

I am just making a normal gamemaker 8.1 game, no HTML5 game (I'd rather script that myself, not with gamemaker as I am really disliking it).

My server code:

```
var net = require('net');
var server = net.createServer(function(socket){
    console.log('connection made');
    socket.on('data', function(d){
        console.log(d.toString());
        socket.write(d.toString());
    });
    socket.on('error', function(e){console.log(e)});
    socket.on('close', function(){console.log('Socket closed');});
    socket.write('hhhaaannbikbkm');
}).listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT||8080);
```

GML code (in the game start event):

```
dllinit(0,true,true);
global.username = get_string("Gebruikersnaam:","");
global.serverip = get_string("Server IP:","127.0.0.1");
global.serverport = get_integer('port', 8080);

global.tcpConnection = tcpconnect(global.serverip, global.serverport, 1);
setformat(2, '<!SEP!>');
if(!tcpconnected(global.tcpConnection)){
    show_message("Connection failed");
    game_end();
} else {
    setnagle(global.tcpConnection,1);
    clearbuffer();
    writestring(global.username, false);
    sendmessage(global.tcpConnection, 1, 1);
    while(true){
        var sock, size, cnt;
        sock=tcpaccept(global.tcpConnection,1);
        show_message(sock);
        //if (sock <=0) break;
        setsync(sock,0);//block untill new package
        size = receivemessage(sock, 0);
        show_message(size);
        //setsync(sock,1);//unblock socket
        cnt = readstring(0, '<!SEP!>');
        if(cnt!=''){
            show_message(cnt);
            clearbuffer();
            writestring(cnt, false);
            sendmessage(global.tcpConnection, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fixed this like a week ago or so. I just don't need to call `sock=tcpaccept(global.tcpConnection,1);`, but just receive the messages with `receivemessage(global.tcpConnection, 9999999);`